# Labels exceeding Boxes when creating UML-Style Dependency Graphs for Doxygen Documentation

Tags: java, documentation, doxygen, graphviz, dot

I am using Doxygen for creating software documentation for a Java application with DOT support to create UML-style dependency graphs. My DOT specific configuration options in doxygen.conf are:

```
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Nimbus Sans
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/
DOT_UML_DETAILS        = NO
DOT_WRAP_THRESHOLD     = 17
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
DOT_PATH               = /usr/bin/dot
DOTFILE_DIRS           =
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

The graphs are created, but in many cases the labels exceed the boxes which is kind of ugly. I googled hard but could not find any fix for this. Any ideas how to fix this?
[image]

Doxygen version: 1.8.14,
dot - graphviz version 2.26.0

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.14 is from December 25, 2017, the current doxygen version is 1.9.4 (from May5, 2022). What happens when yo use the current doxygen version? Can you also try with other fonts e.g. by leaving the `DOT_FONTNAME` and `DOT_FONTSIZE` out of your Doxyfile (doxygen will pick up the defaults). Can you create a small example showing the problem.

Comment: I tried to upgrade to version is 1.9.4 and also removing the  DOT_FONTNAME and DOT_FONTSIZE. However, the issue persists. When I set the DOT_FONTSIZE to 6 the issue of the texts exceeding the boxes persists but the box width is smaller then which is interesting. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: The thing you could do is: Can you create a small example showing the problem, so others can see how to solve it.

Comment: Okay, I created a minimal project. Also here, the class name gets cut at the box border: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k9eax533n2wzon5/minimal.zip?dl=0

Comment: I checked the doxygen output and found lots of these "Error: Could not find/open font" - could this be the cause?

Comment: Regarding the dropbox example, it needs a login, so unreachable for me. Regarding the "Error: Could not find/open font", I don't know what `dot` does here (as it is to my knowledge a dot error, note the dot version is also a bit old). You could look into the generated dot file (set `DOT_CLEANUP=NO`) and also see which commands are exactly executed by doxygen (`doxygen -d extcmd`) so when we have the used `do` command and the `dot` file it might be easier to investigate. (I assume the latest test was with doxygen 1.9.4)